# Modifying Collection In ICommand Delegate Action Not Updating UI

Tags: c#, mvvm

My application currentlys make a REST request, deserializes some JSON and adds the item to an ObservableCollection async (minus adding the items on the UI thread). When binding a ICommand delegate to a button, trying to modify the collection in the action does not reflect on the UI but doing 'ad hoc' delegate Execute() does.

My ProjectViewModel (DataContext)

```
public class ProjectViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DelegateCommand AddProject { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand OnLoad { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<Project> m_Projects;
    public ObservableCollection<Project> Projects
    {
        get { return m_Projects; }
        set
        {
            m_Projects = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Projects"));
        }
    }

    private CoreDispatcher MainDispatcher = null;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ProjectViewModel()
    {
        MainDispatcher = Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher;
        Projects = new ObservableCollection<Project>();

        OnLoad = new DelegateCommand(
            async (p) => 
            { 
                await GetProjectsAsync();

                //Test = Works!
                Projects.Insert(0, new Project() { Name = "Steve" });
            },
            () => { return true; }
        );

        OnLoad.Execute(null);


        AddProject = new DelegateCommand(
            (p) =>
            {
                Projects.Insert(0 , new Project() { Name = "Test", Key = "Test", Avatar = null });
            },
            () => { return true; }
        );

        //Test = Works!
        AddProject.Execute(null);
    }
```

Xaml Button:
`<Button Margin="232,0,0,583" Content="Search" Background="White" Foreground="Black" Width="158" Command="{Binding AddProject}"/>`

GridView:

```
        <GridView x:Name="ProjectListView" Margin="0,107,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ProjectTemplate}" Height="533">
        <GridView.DataContext>
            <vm:ProjectViewModel/>
        </GridView.DataContext>
    </GridView>
```

The delegate executes as expected and I can see the items being added to the collection using Debug.WriteLine however, they just don't show on the GridView when executing the delegate from the UI. Also worth noting, the CollectionChanged event does get called.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, thank you!!

Comment: 1) Does it work when you use `Add` instead? 2) What does `GetProjectsAsync` do? 3) What happens if you ceate `Projects` observable in UI thread? 4) What happens if you remove the parameter from AddProject? 5) Also, you're setting GridView DataCotext, which indicates that `Button` has to be located inside GridView ItemPanelTemplate? How else would it access it? Are you duplicating the viewmodels?

Comment: 1). Nope, none of the methods (add,remove,insert etc.) work.
2). GetProjectsAsync is an async task which deserializes each JSON object adding it to the 'Projects' collection. Each item is added using the MainDispatcher.RunAsync(priority, action) so items are added on the UI/foreground thread.
3). Exactly the same result, still cannot add/remove etc..
4). Its null by default and is the CommandParameters parameter. I'll try removing it.
5). DataContext is set on the Page so each child 'will' inherit it. I added a datacontext via Button.DataContext

Thank you for your comment @ChrisEelmaa

Answer (score 0):

It appears this issue was caused because the DataContext was set within the GridView.DataContext and at Page within Page.Resources. There must of be been a conflict.